# Filter out all child elements from parent in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to query DOM in Vanilla JavaScript to filter out all elemnts containing the `img` tags from the parent node with class `icon`. Example:

After writing query it should return two elements `<span>` and `<a>`:

```js
<span class="icon"><a href="#">link</a></span>
<a class="icon" href="#">link</a>
```

This should not return anything:

```js
<span class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="asdf"></a></span>
<a class="icon" href="#"><img src="asdf"></a>
```

Using jQuery I can easily achieve this using:

```js
jQuery('.icon').not(':has(img)')
```

I am finding it bit challenging to implement the same in Vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting all `.icon`, loop through them, filter out all that contain `img`

```js
const result = [...document.querySelectorAll(`.icon`)]
  .filter(item => !item.querySelector(`img`))

console.log(result);
```

```html
<span class="icon"><a href="#">link</a></span>
<a class="icon" href="#">link</a>


<span class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="asdf"></a></span>
<a class="icon" href="#"><img src="asdf"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

@qiAlex - Thanks for making this look so simple. I have to make few adjustments to make it work in IE. Below is the code that may help somebody with same requirement:

```js
const iconsArray = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(iconsArray, function (element) {
    if (!element.querySelector('img')) {
        // .....
    }
});
```